# Coxcomb charts in R

Tags: r

I have the following two graphs, the first one is provided, and we need to  modify it to produce the second one. The code is provided below

[image: Coxcomb chart produced by code, areas and heights are proportional to count]

[image: Coxcomb chart with only heights proportional to count, the desired effect]

```
ggplot(data = diamonds) +
geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, fill = cut), width = 1) +
labs(x=NULL) +
theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) +
coord_polar()
```

This is the code that produces the first image, to get the second graph, the geom_bar() call needs to be changed, specifically, stat() needs to be called to manually set the heights. How do I modify this line of code to produce the second graph?

Answer (score 1):

For those who come across a similar issue, I solved this by adding an argument for the y-axis and setting it to `sqrt(stat(count))`. This yields the second coxcomb chart shown above